# react-use-websocket How to open a websocket connection?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, nestjs

I'm trying to open a websocket connection, I'm using react-use-websocket library and everything looks good but when I start the aplication, I see in console a error after try to open websocket. I think the problem is certifications but reading the documentation I'm not sure if certification can be added in config options.

React component code:

```
import { useSocketIO } from 'react-use-websocket';

.
.
.

type Props = ExportDataProps & LinkDispatchProps & LinkStateProps;

 const ExportData: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const [socketUrl, setSocketUrl] = useState('ws://apiws.dev.managementsystem.com/ws')
  const [showActionSheet, setShowActionSheet] = useState(false);
  const [popoverEvent, setPopoverEvent] = useState();

    const {
     lastMessage,
    } = useSocketIO(socketUrl);

.
.
.
```

Application error:
[image]

react-use-websocket library:
[react-use-websocket](https://github.com/robtaussig/react-use-websocket#readme)

Backend Nestjs code:

```
import { WebSocketGateway, WebSocketServer } from '@nestjs/websockets';

@WebSocketGateway(3002, { path: '/ws'})
@Injectable()
export class ExportDataService {
    @WebSocketServer() server;
```

path: '/ws' should be '/wss'???

Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you change your socket url to wss://apiws.dev...

Answer (score 1):

The error message states that the websocket-connection is **insecure**, because it is loaded without **SSL/TLS** - while the page itself uses **https**.

Thus, simply change `'ws://apiws.dev.managementsystem.com/ws'` to `'wss://apiws.dev.managementsystem.com/ws'`.

Comment: I will try it now

Comment: @YoungAlCapone OK - let  me know if it worked :)

Comment: Now a new error comes "WebSocket connection to WebSocket connection to 'wss://"

Comment: @YoungAlCapone could you write out the entire error message?

Comment: WebSocket connection to 'wss://apiws.dev.managementsystem.com/ws/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: t.createOrJoinSocket @ create-or-join.ts:99

Answer (score 0):

The error explains itself:
`Mixed contents` means that there are both secure (https) and unsecure (http) requests from your page.

Only for development purpose you could expose your site in http and connect to websocket with ws://.

In production you definitely should use secure connections (https:// and wss://)